# Taxonomy: Show select options as a dropdown, not multiple

Tags: views, theming, forms

I am trying to display a dropdown where users can divide their article in a certain category. I have created a vocabulary called "category" and added s few fields to them.

I have added this to the content structure where the articles are defined. This works perfectly, however, the categories are not displayed as I desire:

[image]

When I inspect this element, there is a property used:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

I don't want these options to be displayed together. I need a dropdown to let users select one of the categories.

I tried debugging and look for which `html.twig` file is being called, and tried to edit the `select.html.twig` but this did not solve the problem.

[See select.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21classy%21templates%21form%21select.html.twig/8.2.x)

> How can I get these options to show as a dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a taxonomy entity reference to show as a dropdown, there are two things you need to do.

1. Go to the "manage form display" (admin/structure/types/manage/MY_CONTENT_TYPE/form-display) for your content type and make sure the **Widget** for the term field is set to **Select list**.
2. Go to the "manage fields" for your content type and click "edit" for the entity reference for your terms.  Go to the "Field settings" tab and make sure the **Allowed number of values** is 1.  If this is set to 2 or more, Drupal will give you a multiple select, not a dropdown.

Comment: Had no idea it could be this simple. I did step one, but step 2 did the trick, thanks mate!!